# I need a exe file that locks a sertan file until they log in to their account

Tags: exe

so. i need a exe file to let peaple log in to thier account .But i somehow need to get their log in from a site into the exe and have it check it than redirect them to the files where they paid for than i want the peaple NOT to get it on other pc's to so i have to link the hardware id to the account and let it check that to when logging in. i tried multiple times making hardware id detections and trying to save them to a account and then have them log in and redirect to a folder of files that is locked until you log in but never worked your help is welcome

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [ask] to get started with this community. Your question is to broad and it is not clear what you are asking. Are you looking for a software recommendation (off-topic)? Are you facing a concrete issue with you own code (your code is missing AND you did not describe the issue)?

Comment: im sorry im just askin for a code

Comment: Just like something in this video starts at 45 secconds https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3D9LkE-knQ&t=129s